# firefox 3 address bar auto-complete dependency

Tags: firefox, autocomplete, interop, address-bar

**Background:**
Those of you who use FF3 may be familiar with an interesting new attribute of the address bar. It allows you to do sub-string auto-complete in order to filter through URLs that you have viewed previously.

Therefore, if you want to open the following URL:

```
 http://longservernamehere.thatyou.nevercanremember.com/support/asdf1235234/kbid?1245
```

You can simply type any sub-strings of that URL that are sufficient to uniquely distinguish the URL:

```
 long<space>never<space>support<ENTER>
```

This changes the way users can think about URLs, because now all they have to remember are the keywords (sub-strings) that will help narrow down the potential links

**Problem:** This feature is great, but there is a downside. Users have a decreased incentive to bookmark and memorize URLs. This obviously becomes a problem if a User needs to type in a URL at a remote site (for example during a sales call) and they fumble around because they cannot remember the URL of the snazzy product catalogue that they want to show during a meeting.

Obviously, there are ways around this problem: bookmark your urls and copy your bookmarks to your laptop before you go on a meeting; use a third-party solution or online bookmarking portal; social bookmarking sites and so on.

**Question**
The question is, for those users who do not want to use any of the above workarounds, is there actually a way to **directly** dig into the FF3 internals so I can write a script that will extract the components necessary to replicate a users auto-complete behavior on any machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox stores all this information in [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) databases. You can query it directly if you have SQLite installed. You can also browse it using the [SQLite Manager](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/) Firefox plugin.

In summary, the url history is stored in moz_places, and the various "phrases" that you have typed in the address bar are associated with *places* via moz`_`inputhistory, which is a child table.

Their algorithm seems to be: as you type each character into the address bar, query moz`_`inputhistory for matching entries and display them in descending order by use_count.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: This site has a bunch of good information about the Firefox databases: [firefoxforensic.com](http://www.firefoxforensics.com/)